# WooCommerce: error relating to: cart-fragments.min.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a page which is being brought down (no images are rendering) and the following error appears int he console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in cart-fragments.min.js

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this same issue. Thanks to [Magnetize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2688629/magnetize) for pointing out that the Poor Guy's Swiss Knife is the real culprit here. It is no longer supported and you should find a way to replicate the functionality you need and then get rid of it.

In the meantime, you'll find that the immediate problem is a JavaScript object inside WooCommerce that sometimes does not get initialized correctly from the server side. Here is a snippet of code that will you can use as a patch:

```
add_filter( 'wc_cart_fragments_params', function( $params ) {
    if( false === $params ) {
        $params = array( 'wc_ajax_url' => '/' );
    }
    return $params;
}, 20 );
```

It runs late (20) so should not conflict with the proper initialization of the `wc_cart_fragments_params` JS object.

Comment: Thanks! I put your function in my child-theme's functions.php and it worked like a charm!

Comment: This worked for me too, however I later realised I was using WooCommerce Poor Guys Swiss Knife that's not supported since a few years. I removed that and now everything is working again. :) Your solution helped me with a quickfix at first though!